# loading custom .phtml template using custom block

Tags: template, custom-block

I am trying to load a custom .phtml template using custom block. But the template isn't loading. I saw similar problems here and tried to figure out a solution, but couldn't find out where the problem is. My controller is working correctly. The url http://localhost/magento/test/index loads view correctly, but without testlayout.phtml contents.

Hers's my code

\app\code\local\Impulse\Test\controllers\IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Impulse_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout(false);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function testAction() {
        echo "This is test!";
    }
}
```

\app\code\local\Impulse\Test\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Impulse_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Impulse_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <impulse_test>
                <class>Impulse_Test_Block</class>
            </impulse_test>
        </blocks>
    <!--
        <models>
            <test>
                <class>Impulse_Test_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>test_resource</resourceModel>
            </test>
            <test_resource>
                <class>Impulse_Test_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>test_resource_eav_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <test>
                        <table>impulse_test</table>
                    </test>
                </entities>
            </test_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <test_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </test_write>
            <test_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </test_read>
        </resources>
    -->
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <impulse_test>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Impulse_Test</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </impulse_test>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <impulse_test>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </impulse_test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

\app\design\frontend\impulse\theme\layout\test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <impulse_test_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="impulse_test/testblock" name="testlayout_testblock" output="toHtml" template="test/testlayout.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </impulse_test_index_index>
</layout>
```

\app\code\local\Impulse\Test\Block\Testblock.php

```
<?php
class Impulse_Test_Block_Testblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function methodblock() {
        return "this is returned";
    }
}
```

\app\design\frontend\impulse\theme\template\test\testlayout.phtml

```
<?php
    echo $this->methodblock();
?>
```

Comment: Test it moving test.xml file to frontend/base/default/layout/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `<impulse_test_index_index>` is incorrect.

In your case it should be `<test_index_index>`, where Test is the modulename : from `Namespace_Modulename` (`Impulse_Test`), and index and index are the controller and actions.

If you update that in `app\design\frontend\impulse\theme\layout\test.xml` it should work.

Comment: Note if that doesn't work you can also do something like <default><remove name="root"/></default> within that layout XML file just too see if the xml file is working. (that bit of code should remove all the content on homepage if it does then you know the file is being loaded)